# jOOQ select for update nowait does not throw when row is locked

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

When using select for update nowait with jooq the statement didn't throw an exception, but instead kept on waiting for the row to get unlocked.

Recently I tried to use select for update nowait in jooq running in spring boot, like so:

```java
 public void findByIdForUpdateNoWait(UUID id) {

        dslContext.select()
                .from(PAYMENT)
                .where(PAYMENT.ID.eq(id))
                .forUpdate()
                .noWait()
                .fetch();
    }
```

And wrote a test to check the behaviour:

```java
    @Test
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    void findByIdForUpdateNoWait_fail() {

        UUID id = UUID.fromString("3d346f2f-9c44-4e8c-8479-f3eb4b46195f");
        repository.findByIdForUpdateNoWait(id);
        testTransactionProvider.runInSeparateTransaction(() -> {
            assertThrows(DataAccessException.class,()->{
                repository.findByIdForUpdateNoWait(id);
            });
        });
    }
```

where method **runInSeparateTransaction** is:

```java
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void runInSeparateTransaction(Runnable test) {

        test.run();
    }
```

The test method is stuck. I see in logs that jooq throws an error **DataAccessException**, but the error doesn't reach the test method.
Here is the query that jooq generates (based on logs)

```
select "payment"."id" where "payment"."id" = '3d346f2f-9c44-4e8c-8479-f3eb4b46195f' for update nowait
```

When querying the database directly at the moment of test run (when another transaction has locked the rows) using this sql:

```sql
select * from payment ipi where ipi.id = '3d346f2f-9c44-4e8c-8479-f3eb4b46195f' for update nowait;
```

The query throws the lock exception as expected.

How should I create the jOOQ query so it throws when rows are locked just like with the native query instead of waiting for them to get unlocked?

I have read the official docs https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/for-update-clause/

I am using jOOQ 3.14.16 with postgres 42.6.0

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL that jooq generated? If so, post it - if not, it might help you (and potential helpers) understand what's going on.

Comment: @Shorn yep, thanks for the input. I have added it to the problem description

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was that I was using

```java
@Sql(scripts = "/sql/payment-tear-down.sql", config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = ISOLATED), executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
```

which actually couldn't run because the transaction was still holding locks on the table, hence it hanged the test and the test never passed.